# Status bar is going to hide when a dialogbox pops

Tags: android, dialog, statusbar

I have an activity with a `listview`, and `onClick` of items, I have to show a dialog box with full screen theme `( android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)` on Dialog box is visible the activity's statusbar Visibility gone. I have theme of  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in manifest for that activity.

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have add CoordinatorLayout View to  the root tag with and fixed the issue.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, working for me

add this to your **AndroidManifest.xml** in respective activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and in that activity add to parent main layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: try by adding adjustResize|adjustPan